# How to use proxy when using URI.open in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, proxy, open-uri

I am parsing a web page using `nokogiri` gem like the code below:

```rb
require 'open-uri'

url = 'https://www.google.com/' # example url
Nokogiri::HTML(URI.open(url))

# ... some other codes
```

I would like to use proxy with `open-uri`. I have looked through [the documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html), but the example code is without using proxy.

How can I use proxy when using `URI.open`? I would appreciate any help with syntax explanation or some example code. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`URI.open` is designed to be an easy to use wrapper for `Net::Http` but I think you have at least a couple of options:

- URI.open (and URI generically) supports the use of an HTTP_PROXY environment variable, like: [Automatically adding proxy to all HTTP connections in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868507/automatically-adding-proxy-to-all-http-connections-in-ruby)
- `Net:Http` has options that would allow you to fine tune this and use different types of authentication with the proxy, and it's not particularly hard see: [How to set a proxy in rubys net/http?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792999/how-to-set-a-proxy-in-rubys-net-http)